# Is などなど a phrase-ending expression or it can be used in the middle of a sentence?

Tags: particles, conjunctions

I recently learned the word などなど which means "etcetera", just like the good ol' など :

> 日本のものはポップでクール！車、オーディオ、家電製品、ファッション、文房具**などなど**。

> フルーツが好きです。りんご、みかん、バナナ**などなど**。

Judging from these examples, I feel that this is an expression only used at the end of a phrase, but I haven't been able to find more examples beyond the ones above, which come from my textbook 上級へのとびら and from [this Q&A post](https://hinative.com/ja/questions/313406) respectively.

Is などなど indeed a phrase-ending expression or it can be used in the middle of a sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [BCCWJ](https://clrd.ninjal.ac.jp/bccwj/), your feelings are mostly right. But it is not impossible to use などなど in the middle of a sentence. A few samples:

> ＣＤ‐Ｒ，　ＣＤ‐ＲＷ，　ＤＶＤ‐Ｒ，　ＤＶＤ‐ＲＷ，　ＤＶＤ‐ＲＡＭ，　ＭＯ  などなど    が含まれます。

> 「え？　このゴミ、何か月分？」「え？　ビールのストックがあるの？」 などなど    何でも構いません

> 預金がいくら以上、住宅ローン借り入れ、給与振込み、 などなど    いくつかの条件を満たしていると、振込み手数料、時間外手数料全て無料になります。

などなど looks more colloquial at least when used in the middle of a sentence. Also it sounds emphasizing the number of 'others' than など (like *and many others, and more*).

Comment: Fantastic resource for looking up expressions in sentences. Thank you